# Using chdir() to read all csv files in a directory

Tags: python, csv, glob, chdir

Here is an example of my directory:

```
Auto
├── Test
│   └── Test.csv
├── Test2
│   └── Test2.csv
└── new.csv
```

I am trying to read all the csv files in the directory.

Here is my code:

```
import glob, os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Auto')
for file in glob.iglob('*.csv'):
    print(file)
```

This only prints “new.csv” and not “Test.csv” or “Test2.csv”.

I was thinking maybe I could try the directory name as the following:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Auto\\{}')
```

But, this gives me a FileNotFoundFoundError as the system cannot find the directory specified.

Comment: There's a canonical duplicate for this regardless of what the actual directory structure is, but I think something's wrong with the diagram. Is `Test2` supposed to be inside `Test`, or directly within `Auto`? Why are there two separate lines pointing at `new.csv`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I probably did mess up the diagram. I have a folder named “Auto”. Inside the “Auto” folder I have a csv file named “new” and 2 more folders named “Test” and “Test2”. Inside the “Test” folder there is a csv file named “Test” and inside the “Test2” folder there is a csv file named “Test2”. I want to print all 3 csv files.

Comment: I fixed the diagram to match that description. Please see the linked duplicate for an answer to your question, and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420280 for help with making such diagrams.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank You! I will read through this.

Comment: Using `chdir` would really not be a reasonable approach IMO. As noted in the duplicate or the answer below, you don't have to do anything because the `glob` module can handle this, but even if it couldn't, you should instead use an absolute path and construct it before passing it to `glob`, don't actually change the working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glob iterates by default only through the root dir, no subdirectories

```
import glob, os

for file in glob.iglob(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Auto\**\*.csv', recursive=True):
    print(file)
```

Comment: I have changed the code to add recursive=True and it still only shows “new.csv”

Comment: Have you also modified your path? See my example, you need `**\\*.csv`